# How to show basic map with marker location?

Tags: google-maps

Google Maps is really expensive and just blows through the roof with each API request. Is there a free alternative? or am I misconfiguring the map API wrong?

Comment: https://www.openstreetmap.org.

Comment: a lot less  expensive is  bingq ..  anyway the free cartographic resource par excellence is OSM   .. (and i bit less  expensive is mapbox).. PS  .. based  on your normal behaviour this  question should be downvoted  and closed   ..as  to broad and  primarly opinion based .. anyway if you need  more let me know

Answer (score 1):

You may consider using [Google Maps Embed API -Basic](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide#basic_map_modes) which is free of charge. Here is a sample of a basic map with a marker location:

```html
<iframe
  width="600"
  height="450"
  frameborder="0" style="border:0"
  src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=AIzaSyAMkCFYbtHQUzcqUcmk4J2jXoq8M6T-6U4&q=1600 Amphitheatre Parkway
Mountain View, CA 94043" allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
```

Comment: You probably don't want to leave your own API key in there!

Comment: Don't worry, the API key is properly restricted. Thanks for reminding.